# Time series has no or less than 2 periods

Tags: r, time-series

Coding to forecast using ARIMA model. The data is one single column in .txt file and it is **Once** every year. (tornadoes per year) Therefore, the frequency = 1, However, it gives me an error when i try to **decompose** it "time series has not or less than 2 periods". I have looked at other answers, however, i can't follow them correctly. I am new to R. Below is the code i am using.

```
tornadoes <- read.table("http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3k/144533803481.txt")
tornadoestimeseries <- ts(tornadoes, frequency=1, start=c(1949,1))
tornadoestimeseries
plot.ts(tornadoestimeseries)

tornadoestimeseriescomponents <- decompose(tornadoestimeseries)
plot(tornadoestimeseriescomponents)
```

Comment: Are these monthly observations? I am guessing you want `frequency=12` in the definition of `tornadoestimeseries`?

Comment: Yes, with frequency <= 1 decompose always raises that error

Comment: They are average tornadoes each year. Basically, we are given data for average yearly tornadoes for 64 years and are asked to forecast the next 4 years.

Comment: @digEmAll So how do i get rid of that error then?

Comment: There's no way... decompose works on subperiods of year (months, weeks etc), you probably need something else...

Comment: Yeah :( Its due in 3 days... If you can help me it would be a life saver. So basically we are given data for each month for 64 years. Then there is another column which has the 'average' for each year, so there are 64 numbers in the average column. So we are asked to find the averages for the next 4 years. So how dont i need to decompose the average column? and i only work with the annual average column right?
thanks anyways :P

Comment: You don´t need to decompose. There is no "seasonality" since it is a annual number. Just use a regular arima process and not sarima. If you had monthly observations then it would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reach your file, so I created another time series.
I divided your data into multiples of 12 periods.
See if this helps:

```
tornadoes <- c(100,50,100,80,70,80,90,200,140,20,30,50,100,70,90,200,120,100,60,70,110,40,80,100,110,110,210)
tornadoes12=c(matrix(data=tornadoes,ncol=length(tornadoes),nrow=12, byrow = TRUE))/12
tornadoestimeseries <- ts(tornadoes12, frequency=12)
tornadoestimeseries
tornadoestimeseriescomponents <- decompose(tornadoestimeseries)
plot(tornadoestimeseriescomponents)
```